# What is a systemd scope for?

Tags: systemd

I just like to know what is a scope for. However this (https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/ControlGroupInterface/) a great summary, in the same time it's a little bit confusing to me.

Part of the article:

> "Services, scopes and slices may be created freely by the administrator
>   or dynamically by programs."

- What are the benefits, the purpose using a custom scope?
- The only way to create a scope (without programming) is the systemd-run --scope?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I previously posted [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/900167/459227) on the topic, take a look to see if that answers it for you.

In short, a scope is a way to create cgroups for a process tree, while systemd is not the one spawning the process itself (as it always does for service units.)

Using `systemd-run --scope` is a good example of starting a new scope (and the process itself will be started by `systemd-run`, not by systemd PID 1.)

> What are the benefits, the purpose using a custom scope?

From the isolation point of view, similar to running a service. You can do accounting and impose limits on resources such as CPU, memory, etc. for that particular group of processes.

And benefits of using a scope other than a service is that you can launch the process from your current environment, don't have to launch it through the system manager. In particular, that allows you to have processes running in scopes that are connected to a local context, such as an X11 server, or an SSH connection or with access to an ssh-agent, etc. You can move any process (even existing one) to a scope you create, while services will always launch new processes and typically with a sanitized environment.

> The only way to create a scope (without programming) is the `systemd-run --scope`?

There are other ways to start a scope. For example, using the `busctl` tool is a possibility, but it's hard to tell whether you'd think of that as "programming" or not... But that would allow you to move an existing process to a newly created scope, which `systemd-run` can't do by itself.

I hope you find these pointers helpful.

Comment: A more practical example: you can run `systemd-run --scope -p MemoryLimit=1G firefox`, but you can't `systemd-run -p MemoryLimit=1G firefox`. Or rather, you can, but Firefox not gonna find DISPLAY variable *(when running on X11)* and fail.

Comment: Leaves the question open: [What is the difference between a slice and a scope?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/688298/what-is-the-difference-between-a-systemd-scope-and-a-systemd-slice)